# IIS 7.0 and asp.net

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

So... I've built my web application (asp.net mvc)

So far I have used the dev server. Works lovely.

Now I want to test performance running on iis 7.0

For the life of me I cant work out how to get the web app running.

At the moment, Visual Studio wont set up the virtual directory - stating that I need to install a bunch of components - asp.net, IIS 6.0 configuration compatability/meta base and windows authentication.

How do I do this? Any help will be appreciated!

Can anybody recommend a walkthrough for an iis 7.0 newbie?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to configure my ASP.net MVC application on IIS 7.0:

I created a directory for my website (e.g. C:\mytestwebsite)

I copied all the files for my website into this directory.

Then I opened up IIS 7.0 Manager and added a new application by expanding sites on the left, right clicking on my site (Default Web Site) and clicking Add Application. Type in an alias for your application (e.g. mysite) this will be how you access your mvc application (e.g. http://localhost/mysite). Then click the elipsis (...) next to Physical Path and choose the folder you copied your files to. Click OK. Click OK.

You should now be able to browse to http://localhost/`<`alias`>`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your IIS 7 install is missing a bunch of features, specifically the ones that enable IIS 6 automation against IIS 7.

You can run OptionalFeatures.EXE

[alt text http://learn.iis.net/file.axd?i=835](http://learn.iis.net/file.axd?i=835)

to check what's installed and install those that are required.

You can also run the following:

```
START /W ocsetup Web-Windows-Auth
START /W ocsetup IIS-ASPNET
START /W ocsetup IIS-ASPNET
START /W ocsetup IIS-Metabase
```

The OCSetup names are from [Windows Vista Packages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722041(WS.10).aspx), add any that I've missed based off your error message.